# Create a Zod object from a TS interface

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, zod

I am trying to create a Zod object from an interface.

This is what I've tried:

```
import {z, ZodError, ZodRawShape} from 'zod';

export interface Test1<T extends ZodRawShape> {
  device_uuid: string;
  serial: string;
}

const schema = z.object< Test1 >({
  device_uuid: z.string().uuid(),
  serial: z.string(),
});
```

Here I get the error:

```
Generic type 'Test1 <T>' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)
```

Without extending the interface Test1, I get this error:

```
Type 'Test1' does not satisfy the constraint 'ZodRawShape'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Test1'.ts(2344)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the point of the type parameter? `Test1` does not use `T` anywhere. Just drop the generic and it'll work.

Comment: why not get the interface/type from the schema, i.e. `export type Test1 = z.infer<typeof schema>;`, that way you have a single source of truth

Comment: I assume they want to get the schema from the output type.

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like to constrain the schema with the `Test1` interface you can do something like:

```
const schema: z.ZodType<Test1> = z.object({
  device_uuid: z.string().uuid(),
  serial: z.number(), // Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
});
```

This will now error if `serial` is not assigned a string based schema.

Comment: This don't trigger intellisense or autocomplete when defining the object shape. Any other solution?